# How to show items in a SharePoint list based on fiscal year?

Tags: list-view, filter, calculated-column

My client has got SharePoint 2007 (yet) and I need to create a view on one of the lists which will show items only for the current fiscal year, which is: 1/4/2016 and 31/3/2016.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create two additional calculated columns:

1. FiscalStartDate:

   **=IF(Created >= DATE(YEAR(Created),4,1),DATE(YEAR(Created),4,1),DATE(YEAR(Created)-1,4,1))**
2. FiscalEndDate:

   **=IF(Created >= DATE(YEAR(Created),4,1),DATE(YEAR(Created)+1,3,31),DATE(YEAR(Created),3,31))**

Now you can create a view with below filters:

```
Where <FiscalStarDate> is less than or equal to [Today]

AND

Where <FiscalEndDate> is greater than or equal to [Today]
```

Change the date format in the calculation which suits your regional setting.

Comment: thanks Unnie. I will give it a try and get back to you soon.

Comment: Thanks man. It helped a lot. I had to change the `commas` to `semicolons` because of the language pack and it worked fine.

Comment: This is the link where I got the idea to change "," to ":" https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/910d98e0-227b-46d6-b128-d9fecf12643d/exception-on-calculated-field?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a view based on those two filters, one per fiscal year. If the Date is Created, use that column, if there is another date column that has users specify the date, like invoice date or something similar, use that.

Create a View
In the Filters section add->

```
Where <Date Column> is greater than or equal to 1/4/2016

AND

Where <Date Column> is less than or equal to 3/31/2016
```

Comment: yes, I have done this but I don't want to hardcode the year. How can I make it dynamic so that it changes automatically based on the year we are?

Comment: the only dynamic thing you can do is to use the [Today] value, which makes it a sliding scale based on the current date and won't give you the results you want. I'd precreate several views filtered as hard coded strings like above to allow user to flip views as they want. Otherwise you are going to have to look into a caculated column or something set in a workflow that updates a column to set a fiscal year.